# An option in a drop down selection is associated with an id, however, when submitting the form the name of the selection does not appear rather the id

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Bascially i have a form which has a selection where if you choose something, the secound selection will change according to the selection you made beforehand.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "support@natechnologies.net"; 
    $from = $_POST['email']; 
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $companyname = $_POST['companyname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
    $selectOption = $_POST['list1'];
    $selectOption = $_POST['list2'];
    $subject = "Consultation submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your Consultation submission";
    $message = $fullname . " " . " would like a consultation for " . "\n\n" . $_POST['list1'] ." ". "specifically," . " " . $_POST['list2']. "The issue is:" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your consultation " . $fullname . " " . " would like a consultation for " . "\n\n" . $_POST['list1'] ." ". "specifically," . " " . $_POST['list2']. "The issue is:" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $fullname . ", we will contact you shortly.";
} 

<form action="" method="post" 
<input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Johnathon Makenzie" required>
<br>
<input type="text" name="companyname" placeholder="Company" required>
<br>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="example@example.com" required>
<br>
<input type="number" name="phonenumber" placeholder="+61 412 345 678" required>
<br>
<select name="list1" id="list1" onchange="updateList('list2', this);"  required>
</select>
<br>

<select name="list2" id="list2" onchange="updateList('list3', this);" required >. 
</select>
<br>

<textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea>

<br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Therefore, I've entered in the data set in Javascript.

```
let data = [{"id":1,"name":"Management","parentid":0},
{"id":2,"name":"Support","parentid":0},
{"id":3,"name":"Digital Business","parentid":0},
{"id":4,"name":"Cyber Security","parentid":0},
{"id":5,"name":"Infrastructure","parentid":0},

{"id":8, "name":"MDM Solution","parentid":1},
{"id":9,"name":"IT Procurement","parentid":1},
{"id":10,"name":"Vendor Management","parentid":1},
{"id":11,"name":"Managed servers, Network, Firewall","parentid":1},       
{"id":12,"name":"Backup and Storage","parentid":1}

{"id":18,"name":"IT Helpdesk","parentid":2},
{"id":19,"name":"Maintenance of Servers","parentid":2},
{"id":20,"name":"Network Maintenance","parentid":2},
{"id":21,"name":"Communication Maintenance","parentid":2},
```

All is working fine untill i submit the form. Instead of showing the name it shows the id of the selection.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncst6.png

I've tried changing the id to the name but then the selection messes up. Then i tried adding a value which had no effect.

Comment: When you submit a `<select>`, it submits the `value` attribute, not the text. You haven't shown how you fill in the options.

Comment: `Instead of showing the name it shows the id of the selection.`...yep, that's how HTML forms work. It's intentional. You shouldn't need to submit the description as well, because it should be already associated with the ID somewhere in your application (e.g. in a database table), so if you need to display the description again you can retrieve that text from the storage, using the ID.